# What is the alternative of <Layout/> of ant design in Material UI?

Tags: material-ui, antd

Alternative of

Trying to find a component in MUI that can wrap the whole webpage.

Answer (score 0):

It's the  "<  Container   /  >" component. It provides a fixed width for the content and can be used to wrap the entire webpage.